# How to solve gcloud cli "4047: 'Failed to lookup instance'" error

Tags: ssh, gcloud

Today, out of the blue, a long time working script give this error on one server:

> # gcloud compute  ssh root@my-server --command=/bin/ls  --tunnel-through-iap --zone=my-zone
>
> ERROR: (gcloud.compute.start-iap-tunnel) **Error while connecting [4047:
> 'Failed to lookup instance']. ssh_exchange_identification: Connection
> closed by remote host**
>
> Recommendation: To check for possible causes of SSH connectivity
> issues and get recommendations, rerun the ssh command with the
> --troubleshoot option.
>
> gcloud compute ssh my-server --project=my-project --zone=my-zone
> --troubleshoot
>
> Or, to investigate an IAP tunneling issue:
>
> gcloud compute ssh my-server --project=my-project --zone=my-zone
> --troubleshoot --tunnel-through-iap

On other servers command work fine!
On the problematic server no updates was done.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of a newly booted system, it takes a while for IAP to register.   I have usually have to add a sleep of close to 60 seconds before a system is ready.   Until then, I will receive this message.

Answer (score 1):

## Problem solved but I don't know why

### How I get the "solution"

After increase ssh verbosity of my command by `--ssh-flag=-v`:

```
# gcloud compute ssh root@my-server --command=/bin/ls --ssh-flag=-v --tunnel-through-iap --zone=my-zone
```

I've found the creating tunnel call:

```
...
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec /snap/google-cloud-sdk/254/platform/bundledpythonunix/bin/python3 /snap/google-cloud-sdk/254/lib/gcloud.py compute start-iap-tunnel my-server 22 --listen-on-stdin --project=my-project --zone=my-zone --verbosity=warning
...
```

And that call (`/snap/google-cloud-sdk/254/platform/bundledpythonunix/bin/python3 /snap/google-cloud-sdk/254/lib/gcloud.py compute start-iap-tunnel my-server 22 --listen-on-stdin --project=my-project --zone=my-zone --verbosity=warning`) give the error.

I do some tries and test and **suddenly it works again**!

### The solution from my "history"

I've updated the system

```
# apt update
# apt dist-upgrade
```

I've installed `numpy` to remove annoying message:

```
# $(gcloud info --format="value(basic.python_location)") -m pip install numpy
```

I've downgrade my google-cloud-sdk:

```
# snap revert google-cloud-sdk --revision=252
```

I've up to date my google-cloud-sdk:

```
# snap revert google-cloud-sdk --revision=254
```

Here the versions:

```
# gcloud  --version
Google Cloud SDK 392.0.0
alpha 2022.06.24
beta 2022.06.24
bq 2.0.75
bundled-python3-unix 3.9.12
core 2022.06.24
gsutil 5.10
minikube 1.25.2
skaffold 1.38.0
```